# How to draw a white frame around the camera preview when taking a picture?

Tags: android

On my Samsung Galaxy S4 the native camera draws a white frame around the screen while taking a picture.
How do I do that on my SurfaceView?

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    hasSurface = true;
    openCamera();
    setWillNotDraw(false); 
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    hasSurface = false;
    closeCamera();
}

public void takePicture(Camera.ShutterCallback cameraShutterCallback,
                        Camera.PictureCallback rawCallback,
                        Camera.PictureCallback postviewCallback,
                        Camera.PictureCallback pictureTakenCallback) {
    try {
        isPreviewStarted = false;
        camera.takePicture(cameraShutterCallback,
                rawCallback,
                postviewCallback,
                pictureTakenCallback);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to take picture");
    }
}

private void closeCamera() {
    if (camera != null) {
        pausePreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: you dont, leave `SurfaceView` as it is and make your frame on its parent `View`

Comment: okay but how do I draw it and how do I make it appear while taking a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, before taking the image:

```
private void showWhiteFrameAroundPreview() {
    GradientDrawable border = new GradientDrawable();
    border.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    border.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    border.setStroke(5, Color.WHITE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        previewContainer.setForeground(border);
    }
}
```

After taking the image:

```
previewContainer.setForeground(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can do it if you are showing your custom SurfaceView in a Fragment where your parent would be the Main Fragment and not SurfaceView Fragment.